# Generating a list of unions from subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

I have

```
s = {a, b, c};
t = {X, {}, {a}, {a, b}};

FindSubsets[candidates_, set_] := Subset[Select[candidates, ContainsAll[set, #] &], set]

result = FindSubsets[t, #] & /@ Subsets[s];

result /. F -> Subset // TableForm
```

[image]

Now, I need the set after the above like this:

```
{{},{{}∪{a}},{},{},{{}∪{a}∪{a,b}},{{}∪{a}},{},{{}∪{a}∪{a,b}}}
```

Comment: You want this just for display purposes? Something like this? `SquareUnion @@@ First /@ result /. SquareUnion[{}] :> {}`. (I can't use the union symbol for this, because it has built in meaning equal to `Union`, so it will actually evaluate the union. That's why I used `SquareUnion` instead that makes the square-bottomed union symbol.)

Comment: Or do you actually want to *compute* the union? In that case, just do `Union @@@ First /@ result`.

Comment: It is work. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this if it is needed in an unevaluated form:

```
Defer@*List@*Union @@@ Map[First, result] /. Defer@{Union@{}} -> {}
```

Output:
[image]